# Hosting child websites on a parent asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-hosting

I want to host multiple child asp.net websites with their databases on one bigger asp.net MVC application.

I want to reach for example one site by typing `www.hostname.com/app1` ...
How i can achieve that?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I think all you have to do is create a virtual map (app1) in the root of the website. Did you try anything?

Comment: do you create a application on you IIS

Comment: I figure it out, there's namespace called Microsoft.Web.Adminstration to control iis.

Comment: Yes, but i want to do it from an asp.net application.
I don't want to do it manually.